# nosetests: algorithms.py:125: RuntimeWarning: tp_compare didn't return -1 or -2 for exception

Tags: pandas, nose

I got the following message while running nosetests `pandas`:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py:125: RuntimeWarning: tp_compare didn't return -1 or -2 for exception
  sorter = uniques.argsort()
```

Is this a serious issue that I need to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please report issues like these on GitHub (http://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues). The warning is not a concern, I may disable the unit test that is causing it.

Comment: Submitted issue #1546. Thanks for a quick reply!